# Why is my login script sending me to a blank white page? Error Reporting on

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a php newbie and I can't seem to get my login script to work. When I enter existing user data and click login it sends me to a blank page. I think it may have something to do with the `if (isset($_POST['login-submit']))` in my code.

Even with error reporting turned on in php.ini the page is still blank. I would appreciate any kind of help! Thank you!

**My users table structure:**

[image: My users table structure]

Below I have attached the code for both my login script, and the `header.php` where the script runs. 
**login-inc.php:**

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);


    if (isset($_POST['login-submit'])){

    require 'dbh-inc.php';

    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    if (empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=emptyfields");
        exit();
    }
    else{
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_uid=?";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)){
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    }

    else{

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $uid);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $pwdCheck = password_verify($pwd, $row['user_pwd']);
            if ($pwdCheck == false){
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
            exit();
        }
        else if ($pwdCheck == true){
            session_start();
            //Stores the user's id, username, and user type in the session
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
            $_SESSION['user_uid'] = $row['user_uid'];
            $_SESSION['user_usertype'] = $row['user_usertype'];
            header("Location: ../index.php/?login=success");
            exit();
        }
        else{
            header("Location: ../index.php?error=wrongpwd");
            exit();
        }
    }
    }
        //Closes the prepared statement and the db connection
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        mysqli_close($conn);

    }
    }


    ?>
```

**header.php:**

```
<?php

    ini_set('display_startup_errors', true);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);
    require "includes/dbh-inc.php";

?>

<title>  </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interfacestyles.css">
    <body>
<header>      
        <nav>
        <div class=”main-wrapper”>
          <div class=”nav-login”>
              <a class="account" href="">My account</a>
              <?php
              // if user not logged in, show login button and input fields
               if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            echo '<form action="includes/login-inc.php" method="POST">
                <input type=”text” name=”uid” placeholder=”Username”>
                <input type=”password” name=”pwd” placeholder=”Password”>
                <button type=”submit” name=”login-submit”>Login</button>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                New? Register <a href="signup.php">here</a>
            </form>';
               }
              // if user is logged in, show log out button
               else if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
           echo '<form action="includes/logout-inc.php" method="POST">
            <button type=”submit” name=”login-submit”>Log out</button>
          </form>';
        }
             ?> 
        </div>
        </div>
        </nav>         
</header>
```

Comment: A good debugging point would be to display your `$_POST` variables at the start of the script - see what is being sent. (`print_r($_POST);`)

Comment: Is this your real code? The quotes in the html look very wrong. Also, don't redirect when you encounter an error while you are debugging, instead show the complete error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Comment: wired if else else else if ...you have one if and 2 else for that...

Comment: An even better debugging point would be to install and use Xdebug

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss to start the session on header.php file, try to put `session_start();` at top of file

Comment: correct. session is not start hence it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I added the "session_start();" to the top of the header.php but now I'm getting the error "Notice: session_start(): A session had already been started - ignoring in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyWebsite\header.php on line 7". Still not working.

Comment: Becouse you add 2 session_start() one in header and the other login_inc.php, so when you include the login file the session in already started and give you the error